# @Secured annotation on a class does not apply to parent class methods

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, aop

I have an abstract class (the parent class) with some shared `@RequestMapping` methods and there are some `@Controller` classes implementing it (the sub-classes).

I annotated the sub-classes with `@Secured` at the class level, but the parent class methods are not protected by this. (I.e. the AOP interceptor only considers the methods on the sub-classes, not the parent class).

Unfortunately, the sub-classes each need to be protected by a different role, so it will be impossible to annotate the parent class with a common `@Secured` restriction. It is possible to override all methods in the parent class so they are protected, but I want to avoid this ugly workaround.

Thus I am wondering is there anything I can override (e.g. the interceptor, advice or the meta data provider so that any method in the class hierarchy will observe the `@Secured` annotation on the target class)?

Additional info:

It seems the annotation resolution is implemented in 
[org.springframework.security.access.method.AbstractFallbackMethodSecurityMetadataSource](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/method/AbstractFallbackMethodSecurityMetadataSource.java)`.getAttributes(Method, Class<?>)` and indeed it only looked at the declaring class of the method (in my case, the parent class). However, I am not too familiar with proxy programming, so any advice on how to safely implement the changes I want are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can simply override `SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` with something like

```
@Override
public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
    Collection<ConfigAttribute> out = super.getAttributes(method, targetClass);

    if (out == null || out.isEmpty()) {
        out = findAttributes(targetClass);
        if (out == null) out = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    return out;
}
```